# Why I cant call method from other class when implementing custom authentication provider

Tags: java, spring-security

I have custom  authentication provider. When I want to call method from other class nothing happens and I have no idea why. Please help:

```
package org.sample.web.security;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.sample.web.service.SimpleService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.error("1111111111111111");
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        simpleService.doNothing();
        logger.error("2222222222222222");

        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    public void setSimpleService(SimpleService simpleService) {
        this.simpleService = simpleService;
    }
}
```

output of authentication method is just:

```
DEBUG - ProviderManager            - Authentication attempt using org.sample.web.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider
ERROR - stomAuthenticationProvider - 1111111111111111
```

when I commend line do nothing

```
//            simpleService.doNothing();
```

then it start working why ?

```
DEBUG - ProviderManager            - Authentication attempt using org.sample.web.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider
ERROR - stomAuthenticationProvider - 1111111111111111
ERROR - stomAuthenticationProvider - 2222222222222222
TRACE - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureProviderNotFoundEvent[source=org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9561: Principal: aaa; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities]
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'methodRegistrar'
DEBUG - BasicAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
DEBUG - nSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG - tyContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

security context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it seems that method  simpleService.doNothing() never returns,
thus causing your thread to get stuck,
that is why the other code in your authenticate() method isn't reached.

And by the way, a simple test with the debugger should reveal the problem easily.

**Edit:**
Since I understand debugging is not an option here, the way to go is to print to log 
before calling the method, inside the method and after the method.

Since you've done it and the method doesn't print, there are now 2 options:

1. simpleReceiver is null, a simple try catch with logs should reveal it.
2. simpleReceiver is not of type SimpleReceiver but a derived class that does infinite long work
   in its function, if that is the case a simple log print of the instance type should reveal it.

Comment: doNothing really do nothing:     public void doNothing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

Comment: hm I have no idea how to debug this login

Comment: Not if when you commented it out the code works and when you call it doesn't. have you looked in the debugger?

Comment: exactly but dont know how to debug web application

Comment: If you can't set a breakpoint, (for reasons I don't understand I might say) , at leaset add some logs : about to call doNothing, inside doNothing() , exited doNothing() etc..

Comment: I try this. When I call logger inside doNothing nothing prints

Comment: I now understand that this is a part of the code managed by the framework, maybe an excpetion is called? most likely simpleService is null , the framework handles this exception quielty , so you don't know about it. try doing try catch maybe?

Comment: eh omg you are right. so stupid mistake but I relly except when this is null it throw NPE

Comment: Glad I could help , updated my answer- please upvote if you can :)